Deployed React App Returns "undefined" is Not Valid JSON Error on Campaign and Login
Title: Error "undefined" is not valid JSON in Production for React App
I recently deployed my React application at https://fundingfriends-frontend.onrender.com/. However, when I click on a campaign (for example, the first one), I encounter the following error:
react-dom.production.min.js:188 
SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at useToken.js:6:32
    ...

Similarly, when I try to log in, I get the same error:
react-dom.production.min.js:188 
SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at useToken.js:6:32
    ...

This is my first time deploying on Render, and my backend seems to be working fine. I can access the following API endpoints without any issues:

https://fundingfriends-backend.onrender.com/api/v1/campaigns
https://fundingfriends-backend.onrender.com/api/v1/donations
https://fundingfriends-backend.onrender.com/api/v1/users

Relevant Code
useToken.js:
import { useState } from "react";

export default function useToken() {
    function getToken() {
        const tokenString = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
        const userToken = JSON.parse(tokenString);
        if(userToken) {
            console.log("Found userToken");
            return userToken;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    const [token, setToken] = useState(getToken());

    function saveToken(userToken) {
        localStorage.setItem('accessToken', JSON.stringify(userToken));
        setToken(userToken);
    }

    return {
        token, setToken: saveToken
    }
}

Component Where Error Occurs (CampaignDetails.js):
import { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import useToken from 'src/hooks/useToken';
import { APIURLContext } from 'src/contexts/APIURLContext';
import 'src/pages/CampaignDetails/CampaignDetails.css';

function CampaignDetail() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [campaign, setCampaign] = useState({ campaign: {}, donations: [] });
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const { token } = useToken();
  const apiURL = useContext(APIURLContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const campaignResponse = await axios.get(`${apiURL}/campaigns/${id}`);
        setCampaign(campaignResponse.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching campaign data:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [id, apiURL]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoggedIn(!!token);
  }, [token]);

  const totalDonations = campaign.donations.reduce((total, donation) => total + donation.amount, 0);
  const progress = (totalDonations / campaign.campaign.goal) * 100;

  const handleEmailShare = () => {
    const subject = 'Check out this donation campaign!';
    const body = `Hi there,\n\nI found this donation campaign that I think you might be interested in. \n\nHere's the link: ${window.location.href}\n\nBest regards,\n[Your Name]`;
    window.location.href = `mailto:?subject=${encodeURIComponent(subject)}&body=${encodeURIComponent(body)}`;
  };

  const handleSmsShare = () => {
    const message = `Check out this donation campaign: ${window.location.href}`;
    window.location.href = `sms:?body=${encodeURIComponent(message)}`;
  };

  return (
    <div className="details-page-container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
          <div>
            <h1>{campaign.campaign.name}</h1>
            <p>{campaign.campaign.description}</p>
            <p>
              <span className="donation-amount">${totalDonations} </span>
              raised of ${campaign.campaign.goal}
            </p>
            <p>{campaign.donations.length} donations</p>
            <p className={`funded-status ${progress >= 100 ? 'funded' : ''}`}>
              {`This campaign is ${progress.toFixed(2)}% funded!`}
              <div className="progress">
                <div className="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style={{ width: `${(totalDonations / campaign.campaign.goal) * 100}%` }} aria-valuenow={(totalDonations / campaign.campaign.goal) * 100} aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
              </div>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className="mt-3">
            {isLoggedIn && (
              <form action={`${apiURL}/donations/create_checkout`} method='POST'>
                <input type='hidden' name='campaign_id' value={campaign.campaign._id} />
                <input type='hidden' name='campaign_name' value={campaign.campaign.name} />
                <input
                  type='number'
                  id='donation_amount'
                  name='donation_amount'
                  min='0'
                  step='0.01'
                  defaultValue='30.00'
                />
                {token && <input type='hidden' name='token' value={token} />}
                <button type='submit' className="donate-button">Donate</button>
              </form>
            )}
            <button className="share-button" onClick={handleEmailShare}>Share via Email</button>
            <button className="share-button" onClick={handleSmsShare}>Share via SMS</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="row mt-5">
        <div className="col">
          <h3>Donations</h3>
          <div className="donations-container">
            {campaign.donations.map((donation, index) => (
              <div key={index} className="donation-card">
                <p><strong>Amount:</strong> ${donation.amount}</p>
                {donation.payment_id && <p><strong>Payment ID:</strong> {donation.payment_id}</p>}
                <p><strong>Message:</strong> {donation.message}</p>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CampaignDetail;

Question
Why am I getting the "undefined is not valid JSON" error in production but not in development? What steps can I take to debug this issue effectively?

tokenString is undefined when you call JSON.parse(tokenString), because there is nothing in local storage to use localStorage.getItem(). Check tokenString and see if it has value before trying to parse it.
const tokenString = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
if(!tokenString) return null
const userToken = JSON.parse(tokenString);

